# Apache - How to configure (via php.ini or .htaccess) apache to pass POST data to a php file

Tags: php, apache

So when you POST data to a file the content length is say 8mb and may take a few minutes to upload. How do you change apache configuration (for that file) to pass data **as it is received**?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? 8 MB is not much with a good connection.

Comment: An artistic experiment, j.k. I want to do this for no reason other than I want to.

Comment: A loop to echo the contents from the set variable.